# Keep track of application usage (differend session without app closing)

Tags: android, session, tracking

While working on my application I came across a problem I can't find the answer for. I want to keep track on how often the application is used, keep track of the number of session per user. This in itself is not so hard to solve, but the problem is that I've noticed that most of the users actually don't close the application after usage. They just lock the screen.

**So the question, how to know when a new session starts, even if the application is not closed?**

I was thinking in the direction of time difference, but the problem there is that a session for example can last longer than 10 min, but on the other hand the time between sessions can be less than 10 min... Perhaps tracking when the screen gets locked -> end of current session? But how to know when a new one starts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For people in similar situations: my solution was to override the method 'onResume', it is called when the app starts and of course, resumes after the screen locks/closes...